# How can I prevent wasps from eating my apples?

Tags: pest-control, fruits, apples

Last year, as my apples were finally approaching ripeness, nearly all of them got eaten or burrowed into by wasps.

Is there anything I can do this year to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: What kind of wasps were they?

Comment: Let's have a picture of these apples.  Burrowed into by wasps?  Not in any of my experience.  There are insects that lay their eggs in developing fruit and the larvae will burrow OUT.  What kind of wasp?  Long legs or not?  And if you cut to see the cross section of this burrow.  Does it go to the center of the fruit?

Comment: @stormy I have also wasps that dig apples (mainly the red one), leaving at the end only the peel and the core, but eating all the pulp.

Comment: I had no idea, should have.  Now I do!!

Comment: Sorry - not sure of the breed of wasps. If its any help, I think they are just the common wasp from here in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use wasp traps: a PET bottle with apple must, some sugar, few vinegar, and a few drop of dish detergent.

This will reduce damages.

Some people uses nets (if tree is not too big). Only the big wasps are able to burrow apples, or better: only the big wasps could cut the peel (so letting also the other bees and insect to feed).

Comment: Dumb question, but that trap configuration sounds like it could attract & kill bees too - is that the case?

Comment: @Codebeef Unfortunately, yes. Bees are attracted by flowers, not by vinegar (so old fruits) and fruits, but some there are still some casualties.

Comment: Setting wasp traps in spring (especillay with fried chicken or pheromone lures) will capture the queens and prevent hives and hive populations before summer.

Comment: OK, well I set something up. If it gets too bad, then I'll have to invest in something to cover instead. Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 0):

[wasps eating apples info](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/fegen/wasps-in-fruit-trees.htm)

Ok, I went out to check on this and I was wrongo!  This link explained an awful lot.  I've never had this problem but it is a real concern.  Since we are losing our bees, I have also been protecting wasps.  Hornets are a bit different.  You'd know if you were stung by a hornet.  Feels like a sledge hammer and keeps on going if you don't get that stinger out of your skin.  I was putting up a sign in the country and it was like 'on the count of 3 guys'!  They were under my shirt, in my hair and running did not help.  Finally got in my truck (with the buggers) and my dog (who eats these guys) couldn't understand why I was doing these weird frantic movements.  Docs pulled 47 stingers out of me, anaphylactic shock...hornets and wasps love meat and there was dead meat nearby.

I know, TMI, hope this article helps.  Be careful using equipment near any nests as they will come out (hornets and wasps) to attack and somehow it is always in the butt cheeks!